# MKMapView Legal label shows as <unlocalized>

Tags: ios, localization, mapkit, mkmapview

I've added an `MKMapView` as a subview on one of my ViewControllers in an XIB. The map works alright in terms of showing directions. But the `Legal` text on the map (bottom left) shows as `<unlocalized>` instead of having a text saying `Legal` in whatever language is selected (or even English).

How do I fix this? Thanks.

**Note:** My app supports 6 languages if it makes a difference (but none of the XIBs are localized)

Comment: I have localised XIB and it's working fine. Could you please show how you have done it?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn`t reproduce this but it seems like an issue in the localization file. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955810/3253405) has a similar problem and resolved it by removing localization files (and creating new I think).

Of course, you can always set directly your localized string to Legal `MKAttributionLabel`, by getting it from `MKMapView` subviews, and using `setValue(_:forKey:)` with `_innerText` and `_strokeText` keys. But notice that this is private API :)

Comment: Well I can't remove localization. Did remove the file, recreated and added back. No difference. And yes, the attribution label is private, so no can do!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 possible solution but didn't. One is to check which subview of all your MKMapView's subviews for that specific label and add move it out of the window or scale it down to 0. The other one would be similar but by subclassing you MKMapView and try to hide this label in `layoutSubviews` method.